# How to Change a task to In Progress when viewing Task in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Normally I just drag and drop my tasks I'm working on to In Progress from the Available.

[image]

Unfortunately my Available Work Items is Extremely Large, so I open the query, and navigate to the item I want to work on, but I can't figure out how to add it without clicking on the Actions drop down, and typing in the Task Id.

Is there a way so when you're viewing a task, you can add the "Add to In Progress" button to a command bar?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to do it before you check in but if you do it after you check in you just need to link the tasks to the changeset number in bulk via a query